# Pandas.to_csv() decimal parameter

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I had to export numerous pandas dfs to csv files.
The dfs contained numeric values as float numbers (float 64)

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep = ";", decimal = ",", encoding = "utf-8", index = False)
```

I learned the hard way that it is extremely important to specify the decimal character as a parameter (decimal = ",") instead of "." which is the defaut parameter if you work with european data/numbers. That led me to numbers formated as strings instead of floats (impossible to work with furthermore) like :

> "7.48E+17"

It took hours for debugging the code & find the mistake.

Why is it such a pain ? How can I know if the data is european or american style ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you work with Excel? 
And what the problem exact you want to solve: format like "7.48E+17" or that is the string?

If the problem with format: as, then, as I know format like "7.48E+17" is a problem of Excel (if you use it). Furthermore Excel has a limitation for length of cell (look about [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3))

I've tried to save csv with float format and it's ok. I used quoting: as I understand it could help you to convert all non-numeric values as string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[12.12412412421410000,1.247518274658710000, 9.908098210849, 2.19870912870918, 1.2871287012 ],
               [12.12412412421410000,1.247518274658710000, 9.908098210849, 2.19870912870918, 1.2871287012 ]])
df.to_csv('df.csv', decimal='.', 
          header=None, index=False ,
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='utf8')
```